# Constant Voltage of a Peltier TEG Tile

Tags: voltage, peltier

So I have several TEG peltiers, and the main issue that arises is the peltier tile neutralizes in heat over time. Applying my hand's heat to one side will soon affect both sides of the tile, therefore no longer producing voltage. What is the best way to produce a constant voltage? A heat sink on the opposite side perhaps? (if so, suggestions on what type of heat sink)

To summarize, how can I produce a constant voltage in my peltier TEG, or what is the best/closest way to do this?

Comment: You should do some more research on energy harvesting with peltier junctions. Indeed you need a constant thermal gradient and thus thermal flux to produce voltage. This is usually done with a heat source and a heatsink.

Comment: I'm aware of how the peltier works and how to produce voltage, but are you saying that providing a heat source and a heat sink on opposite ends will give it a CONSTANT voltage? Keep in mind by constant, I mean as long as the sources of energy are provided, the voltage will always stay the same. Like I said the problem is that the heat source neutralizes both sides of the peltier and the voltage therefore decreases over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peltier effect delivers a voltage according to the temperatures (which must be
different to create nonzero output) of the junctions.   This can be
made constant by putting one end in an icewater bath, and the other in boiling
water.  Assuming the ice melting temperature and water-at-a-boil temperature
are nearly constant, so will the output voltage be.

This is a common issue with ALL heat engines, the temperature difference
is essential to get any energy out, so energy becomes unavailable when
thermal equilibrium occurs.   The removal of energy from a Peltier device
causes heating of the cold plate, and cooling of the hot plate, in proportion
to the current drawn, so any electrical energy removed will cause the ice to melt faster, and the boiling water to require more fuel.

Comment: Indeed I have heard of the ice water and boiling water method. Can this be done with simply the heat of your hand and a heat sink though? If so whats a good heat sink to use?

Comment: A hand is not at a stable temperature (in cold weather, your circulation changes and hands get cold...), but skin temperature of 28C and room temperature of 20C will give some output.  If the heatsink has to be worn on the body, I'd use something with curved aluminum, not spiky, vanes.   If you have a pet bird, the so-called 'brood patch' would be an ideal site for heat harvesting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I were to go with a simple heat sink for the cool side, is copper a good choice over aluminum? I heard it was the most powerful choice of the two.

Comment: Copper is an excellent heat conductor, just a tad expensive; I've used architectural flashing (circa 0.040" thick) copper for heatsinks.  Anything that feels cold to the touch is a good heatsink material, of course.

Comment: Can you link me to a good option(s)? All the ones i'm finding are suspiciously cheap for copper.